# If two fractions can't be canceled further and their denominators are coprime then also their sum can't be canceled further

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions, gcd-and-lcm

The fractions $\frac{a}{b}$, $\frac{c}{d}$ can't be canceled further and their denominators $b, d$ are coprime. Then also the sum of the fractions $\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$ can't be canceled further.

So we know that $\gcd(b,d)=1$. And since the fractions can't be canceled further I assume that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(c,d)=1$. However I'm unsure on how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

Any prime factor of (e.g.) $b$ that divides $ad+bc$ must also divide $ad$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).